# SQL Server auto determine data type from VARCHAR(MAX) column

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I have a database with lots of tables and many columns. Most columns have the data type of `VARCHAR(MAX)`. Is there a way for me to scan the data and based on that determine which data type is more appropriate for each column? Maybe a C# library? Any other language that is better at doing it would do as well.

Comment: @KenWhite, I think Paul understands varchar(MAX) isn't appropriate for many columns and is looking for a tool to help identify the most appropriate type of each column based on existing values.

Comment: You should know what a logical meaning a column has. That determines the appropriate data type, not the current values.

Comment: Since this question is getting downvoted, adding my 2 cents. For legacy code that's a decade or two old, the intention of a column and its practical usage may not be congruent. An analysis may help understand the current state better (it complements, but doesn't replace the understanding of domain).

Comment: There is nothing *out of the box*... You can use `CHARINDEX()` or `PATINDEX()` to search for the existance of characters and patterns. You can use `TRY_CAST()`, `TRY_CONVERT()` or `TRY_PARSE()` to check for certain datatypes. You might export to Excel and examine how the export tool uses implicit algorithms to find the appropriate data types... And be carefull with cultural differences (decimal format, date/time format etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Assumption is this is an adhoc one-time analysis.

In the past, I've used sql data dumps to do such investigations offline (load the dump in SSMS). It doesn't affect the production traffic if you collect the dump in off peak time. You can choose to use simple `select` with `DATALENGTH` (see [here](https://dataginger.com/2015/06/04/sql-server-how-to-calculate-length-and-size-of-any-field-in-a-sql-table/)) to find the average size, or use the `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS` command if the column is indexed or has stats (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-show-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

Same steps can be used for live analysis as well. Needless to say that you have to be careful.

You can also wrap these in a `ExecuteQuery` or `ExecuteNonQuery` command from the application layer. Given our assumption that this is an adhoc one-time analysis, may be it is not worth the trouble.